# Probability of two electrons of different energy levels contained in a single infinite potential well being found in same region

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, probability, pauli-exclusion-principle

What is the probability of two electrons in a single infinite potential well centered at 0, one in the ground state, the other in the first excited state, being in the same region?

I know by the Pauli exclusion principle they cannot be in the same energy level as fermions are antisymmetric, but what if they are in different energy levels? I am getting that it should be 1/2 to find both electrons in either the positive or negative region for a potential well of width $2L$?